# How to add Image in section in Shopify?

Tags: image, shopify

I want to add Image in the home page and for that, I added this code in customimg.liquid under section

```
{
"type": "image_picker",
"id": "image_1",
"label": "Image"    
}
```

template->index.liquid

```
{% section 'customimg' %}
{{ settings.image_1 | img_url: 'master' | img_tag }}
```

The image is not showing up on the home page.

[image]

Could you please help me where I am missing.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are calling the section like so `{% section 'customimg' %}` instead of using `{{ content_for_index }}` I assume that you like the section to be static.

First you need to read a lot about how to use sections in here: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/sections

#### Issues with your code

The structure inside the section must be written this way:

```
{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Image",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "image_picker",
      "id": "image_1",
      "label": "Image"    
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

This is deprecated `img_url: 'master'` don't use it. Use this instead `img_url: '2048x'` .

This is wrong `{{ settings.image_1 ...`. You must call it like so `{{ section.settings.image_1 ...`

You can't call the image outside the section! You must call the image inside the section, since the `section` object is accessible only inside the section.

---

#### How should your code look:

> sections/customimg.liquid

```
{{ section.settings.image_1 | img_url: '2048x' | img_tag }}

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Image",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "image_picker",
      "id": "image_1",
      "label": "Image"    
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

> templates/index.html

```
{% section 'customimg' %}
```

---

#### As an alternative your code can be dynamic and look like this

> sections/custommg.liquid

```
{{ section.settings.image_1 | img_url: '2048x' | img_tag }}

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Image",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "image_picker",
      "id": "image_1",
      "label": "Image"    
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "Image",
      "category": "Content"
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

> templates/index.liquid

```
{{ content_for_index }}
```

The dynamic way allows you to add the section multiply times from the admin panel instead of a single one.